# Why is password authentication failing when md5 hashing passwords in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a new user on my AWS Redshift cluster. I followed [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) when creating the user and hashing the password, but I keep getting authentication failures when trying to sign in using the real password.

Some example details of what I did:

To create the hash from the bash shell on a mac:

```
echo -n "my_userMyPassword1" | md5
1ce2ff3ac550ebd14b9fbf01e91d84cd
```

And then on the redshift cluster as the superuser:

```
CREATE USER my_user PASSWORD 'md51ce2ff3ac550ebd14b9fbf01e91d84cd' CONNECTION LIMIT 20;
```

When I try logging in as the user from the command line, I get the following error message:

```
psql -h mycluster.myregion.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 1234 -U my_user myredshiftdb
Password for user my_user: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

I verified that the hash is correct using the redshift md5 function. I also created the account when not hashing the password, and I could successfully login. I've tried variants of the password (making it super simple and short) to no avail.

Here's the redshift version I'm using:

```
SELECT VERSION();
                                                         version                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1499
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think it may be appending "md5" to your password.  See how it's saying `PASSWORD '** md5 **1ce2ff3ac550ebd14b9fbf01e91d84cd'`?  Not sure if that's correct.  Also, why are you using md5?

Comment: Following the AWS documentation I prepended md5 to the hash intentionally. Do you have an example of using an alternative to MD5 with Redshift?

Comment: I do not, it just seemed odd and I thought it might have been a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the user / password hash reversed. The password goes first followed by the user.

> echo -n "MyPassword1my_user" | md5

Comment: Ugh. That was it. :facepalm: Thanks!